# Winston: how to log to Console AND Syslog transports at the same time?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I love [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) and use it in all my projects. Now I have a need to log to a syslog server in one of my applications. I thought, "No problem. Winston has a [transport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-syslog) for that. Easy!"

But I have found an issue. The log levels between npm (console) and syslog are not compatible. Example:

In my application I have configured my logs (mostly) like this

```
// To use syslog stuff. Commented out for the initial example
//winston.setLevels(winston.config.syslog.levels);

// Console logging should have timestamps which are off by default
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(winston.transports.Console, {timestamp: true});

// Add my syslog transport
winston.add(
    winston.transports.Syslog,
    {
        level: 'info',
        host: config.app.syslog.host,
        facility: config.app.syslog.facility,
        json: false
    }
));
```

At this point, everything as far as my console logging goes is great. I can

```
winston.info('Info');
winston.error('Error');
```

and I get 2 console logs.

But when I uncomment the `winston.setLevels(winston.config.syslog.levels);` part so I can properly use syslog levels, I no longer get any output to the when I `winston.error('Error')`.

"Hmmmm", I thought. "Maybe having my log level set at 'info' is the problem because `info` and `error` levels are inverted in their order between npm and syslog mappings and maybe Winston only considers increasing log-levels."

```
  value  |  npm level  |  syslog level
---------+-------------+----------------
    0    |  silly      |  emerg
    1    |  debug      |  alert
    2    |  verbose    |  crit
    3    |  INFO       |  ERROR
    4    |  warn       |  warning
    5    |  ERROR      |  notice
    6    |             |  INFO
    7    |             |  debug
```

Armed with this theory, I set `level: error` and tried again. And again, same result.

Has anyone gotten this to work so that I can just

```
var logger = require('winston');
logger.info('Info');
logger.error('Error');
```

in any modules that I please after my initial setup? Each log call should write to my console AND to my syslog.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Transports must also be created with the custom levels (syslog levels). The console transport is created before you add the custom levels. You may have a better chance with this code :

```
logger = new winston.Logger({
  levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
  colors: winston.config.syslog.colors
});
logger.add(winston.transports.Console);
```